# textColor and textAppearance of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, textcolor

Here is my code

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/App_TextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/App_TextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="App_TextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff0000</item>
</style>

<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="App_TextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearance</item>
</style>
```

The problem is, now the textcolor of all textviews are RED, but the textcolor of all edittexts are still black. I know i need to set a android:textColor attribute item to the App_EditTextStyle to change the edittext's color, but why? Is the android:textAppearance attr useless for edittext?

Comment: The android:textAppearance attribute must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".
To change the individual text color you will have to extend the text appearance style.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of changes i have tried out in code and not in the xml part. It can be achieved using `onFocusChangeListener` of an EditText.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText et1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);        


    et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)  //Whenever your EditText is focused this color will be applied
                  et1.setTextColor(Color.RED);           
              else //Otherwise display the text in Gray Color
                  et1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);             
        }
    });

}
}
```

This one had worked for me. Hope it helps for you too.